# how can i upgrade React Native version?

Tags: react-native, upgrade

I have an application on react-native. I need to create 64 bit apk for this. React-Native version 0.35. For 64 bit it starts from 0.59.1. I try to update but i didnt do it. How can i update 0.35 to 0.59.5?

Comment: Show us what you did by posting a snippet of your code / configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are at a pretty older version and u need to manually update all your packages and react native. I will recommend you to keep your code as it is and start merging code as per the latest version of react-native in some other branch. To start with, you need to update version number of react-native in your package.json and follow the process. It will be a big change, so be patient and start with it. Follow up with the errors and it will be done.

To refer to the changelogs, check this link https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-helper

And no matter what, documentation is your best friend. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/upgrading